# Expand background on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image, what I would like to do, is when I hover over it, the hidden part of background-image to display like in the example below:

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

My jsfiddle example:

```css
div.test {
  background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;

}

.test:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

As you can see, in my example the image is just getting larger, instead I want to display another 20px of the image (without compromising border-radius).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example with one html element:

```css
div.test {
    background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: 140px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

.test:hover{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Example with [`clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) and [`shape-inside`](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-inside):

```css
div.test {
    background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    shape-inside: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-position: center;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

.test:hover{
    shape-inside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}

body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Comment: However, is there any other method, which doesn't use that hack 'margin-left' ?

Comment: Negative margin is not a hack. Don't be afraid of it. This could be done differently if you have 2 html elements instead of one.

Comment: Can you show me, how to do that with 2 html elements?

Comment: The transition is a bit `bouncy` with the margin-left property

Comment: Actually, as I was trying to do it with 2 elements I remembered a different way. The result isn't exactly the same but it's buttery smooth. Check out my update.

Comment: I like you second method ;) Much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

you might oversize a bit the background image 
      *(`background-size:auto 90px;`)* and add some padding and reset position on hover *(`.test:hover{padding:10px; margin:-10px;}`)*

**those rules are suppose to be understood by most of actual browsers if not all.**

```css
div.test {
  background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg);
  background-size:auto 90px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.test:hover{
  padding:10px;
  margin:-10px;;
}

body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

---

another possibility is to use an `inset` `shadow`

```css
div.test {
  background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg);
  background-size: auto 90px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /* hide buggy ff render */
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 1px;
  /* end fix ff */
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px white;
}
.test:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px white;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

There is also : `padding`, `box-sizing` and `background-clip`

```css
div.test {
  background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg) ;
  background-size: auto 90px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip:content-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}

.test:hover {
  padding:0px;
}

/* show transparency */
html {
  min-height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, gray, yellow,purple,lime,pink,turquoise, gray, yellow,purple,lime,pink,turquoise);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: I was working on the box-shadow approach exactly like yours but couldn't figure out the buggy edges, nice hacks, learned something new today :D

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to remove `border-radius` property on the hover event:

```css
div.test {
  background: url(http://media2.intoday.in/indiatoday/images/Photo_gallery/emraan_012315020812.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;

}

.test:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Comment: Check the gif I've attached, it's adding around 20px of rounder image with extra photo space.